# Image.php Problem - Post Images Not Displaying In It

Tags: images

When I insert an image into a post and link to that image, the link is sending me directly to the file rather than displaying the image via my image.php template.  How can I solve this?  I haven't been able to find the solution online.

This is not a problem with my [gallery] shortcode, which is bringing me to image.php - just with single images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While inserting the image into the post make sure the Link URL is set to Post URL.

[image]

Comment: Wow... I feel stupid for having asked this.